# How to add a new span in POS customer view? Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I want to add a span in POS customer view . I tried with this code , but doesn't work.

//customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates id="point_of_sale.template" xml:space="preserve">
<t t-extend="ClientDetailsEdit">
        <t t-jquery=".client-details-right" t-operation="append">
            <div class="client-detail">
                <span class="label">Test</span>

            </div>
        </t>
    </t>

</templates>
```

//manifest.py

```
"qweb": [
        'static/src/xml/customer.xml',
        ],
```

What's wrong in my code ? Any help please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I look in Odoo addons an example of extend, the templates is declared like this

```
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
```

in your case your declare the template like this

```
<templates id="point_of_sale.template" xml:space="preserve">
```

And in your module when you write this `id="point_of_sale.template"` Odoo will overridden the base templates. But in the logical of templates the t-name must be unique in all modules.

If I follow this logical you should write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
<t t-extend="ClientDetailsEdit">
        <t t-jquery=".client-details-right" t-operation="append">
            <div class="client-detail">
                <span class="label">Test</span>

            </div>
        </t>
    </t>

</templates>
```

In this solution you don't overridden the template point_of_sale.template but you will create a new template will extend t-name ClientDetailsEdit

PS: For more information I look addons/iap/statis/src/xml/iap_template.xml

And the code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template id="template" xml:space="preserve"> <!-- Id is only template -->

    <!-- LAYOUT TEMPLATES -->
    <div t-name="iap.redirect_to_odoo_credit">
        <t t-if="data.body">
            <div t-raw="data.body"/>
        </t>
        <t t-if="!data.body">
            <t t-if="data.message">
                <span t-esc="data.message"/>
            </t>
            <t t-if="!data.message">
                <span>Insufficient credit to perform this service.</span>
            </t>
        </t>
    </div>

    <t t-extend="DashboardMain"> <!-- And extend template here -->
        <t t-jquery=".o_web_settings_apps" t-operation="after">
            <div class="o_web_settings_iap"></div>
        </t>
    </t>
    
    <div t-name="iap.buy_more_credits" class="mt-2 row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-link buy_credits"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"/> Buy credits</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```